# Alternative to finding files on an ftp server?

Tags: python, list, python-3.5, openpyxl, ftplib

So I've got this pretty gross way of finding specific jpgs on an ftp.
It finds files on an excel I have and checks the ftp.
How would you guys go about making this more correct faster/easier/more universal?

```
ftp = FTP("ftp.helmethouse.com")
g=ftp.login(user ='username',passwd = 'password')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\aaron\Documents\HustleHardRacing\Shoei HJC Colors only.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Shoei HJC full colors and sizes')

def check_line_for_img(line):
    for i in range(2,143):
        x = sheet.cell(row =i, column = 3).value
        k = ['r.jpg', 'top.jpg', 't.jpg', 'rer.jpg', 'rt.jpg']
        line = line[56:]
        if x is None:
            pass
        else:
            for i in range(len(k)):
                y = (x[:-2]+'03'+k[i])
                print(y)
                if line == y:
                    print(line)
                elif y is None:
                    print ('Error!')
                    pass
                else:
                    pass
k = ftp.retrlines('LIST', check_line)
```

Comment: Define "more universal"

Comment: Note: if this code isn't broken in some way, try asking here instead https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I was going to ask "In general what are the best practices for searching a list of items for a specific value." but I can probably just go find that myself

Comment: I'm not really sure what you think is wrong with your approach other than the nested for loop in which you haven two `i` variables.

Comment: You could define `k` outside of the loop... You could use Pandas instead of `openpyxl` to act on whole columns instead of cells...

Comment: It's unclear how you're doing it now because the callback function `check_line()` passed to `retrlines()` is undefined—so first thing you should probably do is [edit] your question and correct that... **then** perhaps folks can suggest alternatives/better ways. That said, you probably would be better off using the command `'NLST'` instead of `'LIST'`.

Comment: Internet [**RFC 959**](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959.html) is also a good resource (i.e. see the description of the `LIST` and `NLST` commands there).

Comment: This is incomplete and pretty horrible code: variables are randomly redefined and branching is non-Pythonic. It would be much better if you broke it into components with clearly defined tasks. But I guess the biggest improvement would be to use a regex to get `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `set()`, for instance:

```
from openpyxl.workbook.workbook import Workbook as _Workbook

def normalize(l, has_ext=False):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if has_ext: l[i] = l[i][:-4]
        l[i] = l[i][:-2]
    return l

wb = _Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
data = [['', '', 'Images'], ['', '', 'r01'], ['', '', 'top01'], ['', '', 't01'], ['', '', 'rer01'], ['', '', 'rt01']]
for row, rData in enumerate(data, 1): ws.append(rData)

x = [c[0].value for c in ws['C2:C6']]
print('x=%s' % str(x))

k = ['r03.jpg', 'top03.jpg', 't03.jpg', 'rer03.jpg', 'rt03.jpg', 'rr03.jpg']

x_set = set( normalize(x) )
k_set = set( normalize(k, True) )
print('x_set=%s\nk_set=%s' % (x_set, k_set))

x_diff = k_set.difference(x_set)
if x_diff:
    print('x_set missing:%s' % (x_diff))

k_diff = x_set.difference(k_set)
if k_diff:
    print('k_set missing:%s' % (k_diff))
else:
    print('k_set missing None')
```

> **Output**:
>   x=['r01', 'top01', 't01', 'rer01', 'rt01']
>   x_set={'top', 'r', 'rer', 't', 'rt'}
>   k_set={'top', 'rer', 't', 'r', 'rt', 'rr'}
>   x_set missing:{'rr'}
>   k_set missing None

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1***